# How to make toggle child?

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc

I create a login frame, that can toggle like usual depending on the situation like login successful, child change. and log out too. but my toggle is stuck in this process. login->logout->login. after 2nd login. the child doesn't want to change back to logout. it stuck. I checked it several times and try all things like add UpdateWindow, SetWindowPos

```
#define LOGIN_BTN 1
#define LOGOUT_BTN 2

class CMainFrame: public CFrameWnd
{
  public:
    CMainFrame()
    {
      Create(
        NULL,
        "Learn MFC",
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        CRect(CPoint(100, 100), CSize(640, 360)));
    };
  protected:
    afx_msg int OnCreate(LPCREATESTRUCT);
    afx_msg void login();
    afx_msg void logout();
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
};

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CMainFrame, CFrameWnd)
ON_WM_CREATE()
ON_COMMAND(LOGIN_BTN, &CMainFrame::login)
ON_COMMAND(LOGOUT_BTN, &CMainFrame::logout)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

int CMainFrame::OnCreate(LPCREATESTRUCT lpCreateStruct)
{
  CButton* loginBtn = new CButton();
  loginBtn->Create(
    "Login", 
    WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | BS_PUSHBUTTON, 
    CRect(CPoint(100, 60), CSize(150, 25)), 
    this, LOGIN_BTN);

  return 0;
};

void CMainFrame::login()
{
  std::string resServer = "token";

  if(resServer == "token")
  {
    // Destroy all childs window
    while(GetWindow(GW_CHILD))
    {
      CWnd* pChild = GetWindow(GW_CHILD);
      pChild->DestroyWindow();
    }

    CButton* logoutBtn = new CButton;
    logoutBtn->Create(
      "Logout", 
      WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | BS_PUSHBUTTON, 
      CRect(CPoint(100, 60), CSize(150, 25)), 
      this, LOGOUT_BTN);
  };
}

void CMainFrame::logout()
{
  CButton* loginBtn = new CButton();
  loginBtn->Create(
    "Login", 
    WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | BS_PUSHBUTTON, 
    CRect(CPoint(100, 60), CSize(150, 25)), 
    this, LOGIN_BTN);
};

class CApplication : public CWinApp {
   BOOL InitInstance() {
      CMainFrame* mainWnd = new CMainFrame();
      m_pMainWnd = mainWnd;

      mainWnd->ShowWindow(SW_NORMAL);
      mainWnd->UpdateWindow();
      
      return TRUE;
   }
};

CApplication app;
```

Comment: This code contains memory leaks - buttons are created but not released. Simplify it by having only one button, which changes its text to "login" and "logout", depending on the current state. Add also boolean flag, which is true if user is logged in.

Comment: @AlexF my real code so long, the position logout button is not there exactly. but in middle. ok i fix the memory leak instead call DestroyWindow. I just delete object handle. delete pChild. But still stuck.

Comment: @AlexF Thank you i fix it now, btw how to call OnCreate that already define  inside logout method? My real code in OnCreate so long. If i copy it to logout. it get duplicated implementation in my code.

Comment: @AlexF After thinking i just wrap my on create implementation into view method. so i can call that later inside logout method. ty